# Is it wrong to use iframes in the following scenario

Tags: php, sql, html, iframe

I have a tree structure, that is dynamically added to by the user. This works ok, and I was planning to add it to my page. The only function it serves is to allow the user to edit or add extra content to the tree view. However, I found that I could just put it in an iframe rather than add to my page the normal way. I have convinced myself, that this is wrong, for some reason. However, it seems to work better and faster this way. Am I wrong to dismiss using iframes. I seem to have thought of them as some sort of hack that beginners use.

Comment: "I have convinced myself, that this is wrong": what is your reason?

Answer (score 2):

If SEO is important to you, putting it in an iframe is a really bad idea.

Comment: I know people mention about SEO, but I am not sure if SEO is relevant as this data is only available to the user. It looks like a normal file explorer so I dont think there will be any issues of users hitting the back button.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing code, it's hard to imagine how an iframe could possibly be easier. Either way, you're just setting yourself up for future pain if you use an iframe. Javascript between your frames will be needlessly fragile and complicated. This is definitely not the place for iframes.

Comment: This will be the only iframe i would use. It is basically just a file tree that looks like a file explorer but using sql. As I mentioned it would not cause usability issues, and I dont want this page to use SEO, as it is personal user data.  the reason i want to use it is that it remembers the state of the tree without reloading it each time. I know I can achieve similar with ajax, but it seems really slow, and in this case a worse user experience.

Comment: "Javascript between your frames will be needlessly fragile": could you elaborate?